# How can we give a single number for a system of equations?

Tags: numbering, align, arrays

I want to type the following equation, as it is..

[image]

> I need the left flower to be right and the numbering also should be right..
>
> How I can do that?
>
> Do we  have an environment like `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}`?

### My work:

I tried out with the following codes, but with that I am getting left brace only and that also very closed to the argument.

I want that the bracket has to be right.

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
  TT^\dagger = Q\\
    T^\dagger T T^\dagger =T^\dagger\\
  T^\dagger T =(I-P)\\
  TT^\dagger =Q.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

And my output is ...[image]

Comment: Have you tried with the `cases` environment ?

If yes, can you send your Minimal Working Example ?

Comment: `mathtools` provides an `rcases` environment which puts the brace on the right.

Comment: 'rcases?` k I will try that..

Comment: can you give me a link for that? @campa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `array`:

```
\begin{equation}
 \left.\begin{array}{l}
  TT^\dagger = Q\\
  T^\dagger T T^\dagger =T^\dagger\\
  T^\dagger T =(I-P)\\
  TT^\dagger =Q.
 \end{array}\right\}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like this:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
  TT^\dagger = Q\\
  T^\dagger T T^\dagger =T^\dagger\\
  T^\dagger T =(I-P)\\
  TT^\dagger =Q.
\end{array}
\right\]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, if the `dagger` means transpose I would tend to use `$T^{\top}$` instead.